# How can i get nested json objects values in single key value pair array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have nested json Objects Array and i want to get values from that nested Array in the format of single key value pair to pass to http call instead of single object i need array

```
[{
   "menu_id":1,
   "parent_menu_id":0,
   "children":[
      {
         "menu_id":2,
         "parent_menu_id":1,
         "children":[
            {
               "menu_id":3,
               "parent_menu_id":2,
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "menu_id":5,
   "parent_menu_id":0,
   "children":[
      {
         "menu_id":6,
         "parent_menu_id":5,
         "children":[
            {
               "menu_id":7,
               "parent_menu_id":6,
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}]
```

I need result in the array format

```
[
   {
      "menu_id":1,
      "parent_menu_id":0
   },
   {
      "menu_id":2,
      "parent_menu_id":1
   },
   {
      "menu_id":3,
      "parent_menu_id":2
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function for that.

```js
function toFlatArray(obj) {
  let result = [];
  result.push({
    menu_id: obj.menu_id,
    parent_menu_id: obj.parent_menu_id
  });
  if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
      obj.children.forEach(child => {
        result = result.concat(toFlatArray(child));
      });
  }
  return result;
}

// added another method to run forEach
function toFlatArrayFromArray(arr) {
  let result = [];
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    result = result.concat(toFlatArray(obj));
  });

  return result;
}

const myObj = [{
  "menu_id":1,
  "parent_menu_id":0,
  "children":[
    {
        "menu_id":2,
        "parent_menu_id":1,
        "children":[
          {
              "menu_id":3,
              "parent_menu_id":2,
              "children":[

              ]
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "menu_id":5,
  "parent_menu_id":0,
  "children":[
    {
        "menu_id":6,
        "parent_menu_id":5,
        "children":[
          {
              "menu_id":7,
              "parent_menu_id":6,
              "children":[

              ]
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}];

console.log(toFlatArrayFromArray(myObj));
```

Comment: Yes  Bunyamin Coskuner

Comment: can we use it with array of objects instead of single object?

Comment: @samkadam well you can do anything you want. It's totally doable. Try to implement it yourself, if it does not work you can edit your question

Comment: Yes it is working fine for single object but i need to with array of objects with nested children nodes , question is updated

Comment: Thanks exactly what i want